# asp cookies to detect mobile site while allowing full version view

Tags: redirect, cookies, asp-classic

I've got both a desktop site and a mobile site. I'd like devices to be detected and direct the user to the mobile site while still allowing them to go to the desktop version if they wanted. I'm doing this via cookies. The first time I open the site with a device, I get directed to the mobile site. But if I open another tab I get directed to the desktop version (I should be directed to the mobile site). I'm guessing I need to add a timeout to the cookie or something, but I'm not sure.

Code for the desktop version:

```
<% If Request.Cookies ("sawdust")("m") = "" Then

REM http://detectmobilebrowsers.com
dim u,b,v
set u=Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT")
set b=new RegExp
set v=new RegExp
b.Pattern="(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino"
v.Pattern="1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-"
b.IgnoreCase=true
v.IgnoreCase=true
b.Global=true
v.Global=true
If b.test(u) or v.test(Left(u,4)) then response.redirect("/mobile.asp?" & Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING")) End If

End If %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Code for the mobile version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.2//EN" "http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/xhtml-mobile12.dtd">
<% REM Option Explicit
    Response.Cookies("sawdust")("m") = "yes" %>
<html>
```

I've tried to expire the cookie before, but just ended up in an infinite redirect loop. Little help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Think about this logically.  When you are redirected to the mobile site `Response.Cookies("sawdust")("m") = "yes"` sets the value of your cookie to "yes".

Then when you open another tab the condition `If Request.Cookies ("sawdust")("m") = ""` is not met, so the detection code inside your conditional statement followed by the redirect is ignored by the server.

You don't need to expire your cookie, just add another condition. In your desktop pages try something like.

```
If Request.Cookies ("sawdust")("m") = "yes" Then
   Response.Redirect("/mobile.asp?" & Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING"))
ElseIf  Request.Cookies ("sawdust")("m") = "" Then
   `Put your original device check code here...
End If
```

For users who choose to view the desktop site on their phones, add logic which gives the cookie another value - "no" would be the obvious choice, then neither condition would be met and the desktop site would be displayed